# Need a ContentProvider to access SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider, inner-classes

I dont really need the code for this, just the structure of doing it.

I am working on an application where i have a BaseAtivity (extends Activity) with a number of methods and an inner class User. All other activities in my application extends BaseAtivity.

The User class has methods that read and write data using SharedPreferences.
So LoginActivity extends BaseActivity, and upon correct login it calls User.login(args) in order to create a shared variable (in MODE_PRIVATE) with user id, user email, and a json with user preferences.

I need to create a Content Provider that will use query() to retrieve data from the logged in User. the content Provider will get data from sharedpreferences and provide them to the appalication calling the Content Provider.

Since my content Provider extends ContentProvider I am not able to extend BaseActivity (that could be a solution). When calling within ContentProvider's method onCreate()

```
User user = new BaseActivity.User();
```

I get the error .... "'com.example.myapp.BaseActivity' is not an enclosing class".

Is there a way to call the inner class User from my ContentProvider?

Comment: hmm do you really need `ContentProvider` in this case ?

Comment: @Ye Lin Aung, I need to provide the functionality to some external apps to access user's data. how could I do that? I was just trying y access SharedPreferences from within the content provider class (so the myContentProvider extends ContentProvider implements SharedPreferences) but when trying to  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(R.string.PREFS_NAME, ""); I get an error error: cannot find symbol method getSharedPreferences(int,String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem like this. I didnt find a way to use the User inner class but access the SharedPreferences.

```
public class UserProfileProvider extends ContentProvider implements SharedPreferences {


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.PREFS_NAME), getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.d("akis", ":::userProfileProvider:::" + settings.getString(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.USER_PREFERENCES), "default"));
        return false;
    }
```

Of course you have to add all methods that must be overridden by implementing SharedPreferences

Comment: By downvoting without leaving any comment about what is wrong with this solution is not a good prcatice. You add nothing to this community.

Comment: Thanks, it saved me time. I was having hard time fetching data from my SharedPreferences from my ContentProvider class.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to access `SharedPreferences` from a `ContentProvider`, you don't even need your `ContentProvider` to implement `SharedPreferences`, because `getSharedPreferences()` is a method of the context which is available from the `getContext()` method of the `ContentProvider` class.

Comment: I have seen uses for this. Android now has deprecated Context.MODE_MULTIPROCESS for shared prefs. I did this for an application in 2014 that uses widgets.

Comment: But you need to return a cursor. How can you return the data as a cursor?